# Rewrite for custom type and custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, rewrite-rules

Hello I created a custom post type using the Types Plugin, this custom type has the slug menu, and my permalink structure looks like that:

example.com/%custom-type%/%category%/%postname%

example.com/menu/temaki/salom-special

In the Types plugin I activated the rewrite option, and configured it to:

menu/%category%

I already added this function to generate my permalinks:

```
/**
 * Show category name in the permalink
 */

function cat_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename){

    if (strpos($permalink, '%category%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

    // get post
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if (!$post) return $permalink;

    // get taxonomy terms
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'item-category' );

    if ( !is_wp_error( $terms ) && !empty( $terms ) )
    {
        if ( count( $terms ) > 1  && is_object( end( $terms ) ) )
        {   
            // uses the parent category 
            $taxonomy_slug = end($terms)->slug;
        }

        else if ( count( $terms ) == 1 && is_object( $terms[0] ) )
        {
            $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $taxonomy_slug = 'other';
    }

    return str_replace('%category%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}

add_filter('post_link', 'cat_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'cat_permalink', 10, 3);
```

The permalink is being generated correctly, I can access the post without any problems. But when I try to access this address: example.com/%custom-type% or this: example.com/%custom-type%/%category% I get a page not found error.

I guess this problem can be solved using a proper rewrite. I tried to fix this problem but I couldn't fix it by my self.. need some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you asked the Types plugin author/support? What did they say?

Comment: no reply until now...

Comment: Your issue here is most probably the same as in your newest question, you cannot use `menu` as your custom post type name, it is a reserved term